# Java Mutable Object as Map Key but using default hashCode()

Tags: java, hashmap

I understand using immutable object as map keys are preferable. But how about mutable objects with default `hashCode`() method (and of course, I don't override the `equals`() method). That should also be fine, since default `hashCode`() uses the object memory address?

Is there anything I miss here?

Comment: If the only thing you rely on is the object's "address", then use an `IdentityHashMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as the `hashCode` and `equals` method always return the same result it is safe to use the object as the key in the `HashMap`.

However you are probably reducing their utility as a key by doing so! The whole point of equals/hashCode is to identify equality between object values, and if you modify the members of an object is it really equal to how it was before the modification?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have a builder method that only builds the object with the same "name", for example. So there will always be the same object for a given identifier. What's mutable is only the content associated with the "name".

Answer (score 0):

Below is hash code with string. However, an issue to worry about is the possible change of implementation between early/late versions of Java of string hash code.

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return "name".hashCode();
}
```

In addition, there is an article [hash collision probabilities](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/)

Answer (score 0):

Mutuable Objects as a Key with default equals() and hashcode() is of no use..

e.g

map.put(new Object() , "value") ;

when you want to get that value ,

map.get(new Object()) ; // This will always return null

Because with new Object() - new hashcode will be generated and it will not point to the expected bucket number on which value is saved, and if eventually bucket number comes to be same - it won't be able to match hashcode and even equals so it always return NULL